# Setting nested NSDictionary and NSArray values

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to be able to be able to set the values of nested NSDictionary and NSArray. For example:

dictionary
          array
               dictionary
                         key1
                         value1

What is the easiest way to get to key1 and set value1? setValueForKeyPath obviously doesn't work with and array.

Comment: Let's consider: `dictionary_a array_b dictionary_c {key1, value1}`. I can imagine how you can get the array_b out of the dictionary_a: using the right key. But then, how can you get the dictionary_c out of array_b? Do you know its index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Objective-C's [Object Subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Imagine the following nested dictionaries and arrays:

```
dictionaryA => arrayB => dictionaryC
```

- `arrayB` is stored under `@"arrayKey"` in `dictionaryA`, and
  `dictionaryC` is stored at index `dictionary_index` into `arrayB`.
- dictionaryC should be set to `value1` for `@"key1"`;

**To set key1, you need to do:**

```
(NSDictionary*)((NSArray*)(dictionaryA[@"arrayKey"])[dictionary_index])[@"key1"] = value1;
```

*See the section **Object Subscripting** in **[Clang 3.3 documentation: OBJECTIVE-C LITERALS](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)** for more informations.*

Comment: Note: This supposes that you know under which key is stored arrayB end at which index is located dictionaryC. If you have an arrayB full of dictionaries, it is a very convenient method to loop through them, using the subscripting syntax `array[index]` and set the keys you wishes.